# The second even sublime number

Tags: code-golf, math, kolmogorov-complexity, number-theory

*easy mode of [my previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251270/78410)*

A perfect number is a positive integer whose sum of divisors (except itself) is equal to itself. E.g. 6 (1 + 2 + 3 = 6) and 28 (1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28) are perfect.

A **sublime number** (OEIS [A081357](http://oeis.org/A081357)) is a positive integer whose count and sum of divisors (including itself) are both perfect. E.g. 12 is a sublime number because:

- the divisors of 12 are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12
- the count of divisors is 6 (perfect)
- the sum of divisors is 28 (perfect)

The next smallest known sublime number is

```
6086555670238378989670371734243169622657830773351885970528324860512791691264
```

which is a product of a power of 2 and six Mersenne primes

$$
2^{126}(2^3-1)(2^5-1)(2^7-1)(2^{19}-1)(2^{31}-1)(2^{61}-1)
$$

These two numbers are the only known sublime numbers as of 2022. The necessary and sufficient conditions for even sublime numbers have been found [in this paper (pdf)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200714113410/http://mathematicstoday.org/archives/V32_2016_5.pdf), but it remains unknown whether odd sublime numbers exist.

It is known that there are no other *even* sublime numbers before the number, but it is not known whether there are any *odd* ones.

### Task

Output the second even sublime number shown above. It is OK to only theoretically output this number in the following ways:

- the program outputs the correct number with probability 1 in finite time
- the program outputs the correct number given enough time and unlimited memory
- the program would output the correct number if the native number type had infinite precision

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: @thejonymyster It is known that there are no other even sublime numbers below that number.

Comment: So... I'm wondering that... Is there any built-in in Mathematica output this?

Comment: [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 76 bytes, optimal solution: `6086555670238378989670371734243169622657830773351885970528324860512791691264`

Comment: "the program outputs the correct number with probability 1 in finite time": do you mean to imply as well that there is no other output?

Comment: @GregMartin I think other output will be considered a loophole. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9447/55372

Comment: Thanks @pajonk! It certainly shouldn't be a valid strategy, but I had thought it needed to be in the specs

Answer (score 8):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 45 bytes

```
print(vecprod([4^i-2^i|i<-[3,5,7,19,31,61]]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN3ULijLzSjTKUpMLivJTNKJN4jJ1jeIyazJtdKONdUx1zHUMLXWMDXXMDGNjNTUhmqB6YWYAAA)

The number is \$\prod_{i\in\{3,5,7,19,31,61\}}(4^i-2^i)\$. In fact, \$126=3+5+7+19+31+61\$.

Another interesting fact is that \$2^{126}\$ is just the sum of divisors of \$\prod_{i\in\{3,5,7,19,31,61\}}(2^i-1)\$. This might be useful for some golfing language if there is a built-in for divisor sum.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
print~-2**31*~-2**61*14448825433<<126
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM6@kTtdIS8vYUAtMmxlqGZqYmFhYGJmaGBvb2Bgamf3/DwA)

Writes out \$2^{31}-1\$, \$2^{61}-1\$, and the bit-shift \$2^{126}\$, and hardcodes the remaining product.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

*Edit -1 byte thanks to [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).*

```r
prod(8^42,2^c(3,5,7,19,31,61)-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY07DsMgEER7nwKJwiAtBdj5kMRdzoGECJFXclgEvj9BbpNimtG8eaVR3pFSFTVgjmmx1sqWC73E1c0GjAtighNcQFuYNJy1VFo2zjKVndGb@S3m1W89Y2U@d9KH9Tbg8sPdj9fZoTIOJeMfTHE4OnyoPx7AbmL8SX2IYaztCw)

Spells out the product.

[@alephalpha's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251355/55372) lead to +1 byte for me, but [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen) found a 32-byte version (see the footer of the TIO link above).

Comment: You can do `8^42` for `2^126`

Comment: @xnor ah, right, thanks!

Comment: (alephalpha's approach could be the same length: [try it](https://tio.run/##K/qfX1CSmZ9XrFGcnFmQmmdraWmp@b@gKD9FwyLOxEjHKC5Zw1jHVMdcx9BSx9hQx8xQU9cQqiDTRheLtE4mSAEA))...

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <sup><s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>16</s></sup> 15 bytes

```
*FsmtB^2dPC"9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8utOLfEKc4oJcBZyfLQhEON//8DAA)

```
*FsmtB^2dPC"9
          C"9  # compressed 3772545
         P     # prime factors (3, 5, 7, 19, 31, 61)
   mtB^2d      # map d: [2**d, 2**d - 1]
  s            # flatten
*F             # reduce on multiplication
```

-3 bytes thanks to @CursorCoercer
-1 byte thanks to @isaacg

Comment: Save 3 bytes by replacing `.U*bZ` with `*F`

Comment: Save 1 byte by replacing `m-^4d^2d` with `smtB^2d`

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•w4н•foD<*P
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@alephalpha*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Dcq9DcIwEEDhVayUyEj2ne/HUsoMwAA0Jg4iBRjFBS2zZA92YAYWMa7eV7xS02VdGjtlImJxgIqiUWM3ihcMENBzZAAmUXQiiORVKYojUISg7MiDxH554GDNcEtbPs4lL9maVM1c7s@0rbU8hnP7vfdX@H56rmUaD6dm2x8)

**Explanation:**

```python
•w4н•        # Push compressed integer 3772545
     f       # Get its prime factors: [3,5,7,19,31,61]
      o      # Get 2 to the power for each of these integers
       D     # Duplicate the list
        <    # Decrease each by 1 in the copy
         *   # Multiply the values at the same positions in the two lists
          P  # Get the product of this list
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tips of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•w4н•` is `3772545`.

Comment: -2 bytes: `•w4н•foD<*P`

Comment: @alephalpha Ah, of course. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
»;⟑L»ǐE:‹*Π
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCuzvin5FMwrvHkEU64oC5Ks6gIiwiIiwiIl0=)

-1 byte thanks to alephalpha and -2 bytes thanks to Mukundan314.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
“¤¦¬Œþ=‘2*’æ«21P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//4oCcwqTCpsKsxZLDvj3igJgyKuKAmcOmwqsyMVD//w)

-1 byte thanks to xnor.

Comment: Might it be shorter to multiply each list element by `2^21` instead of the bit-shift at the end?

Comment: @xnor It's `2^126`, and it's longer (`“¤¦¬Œþ=‘2*’P×2*126¤`)

Comment: I meant to multiply each element of `[7, 31, 127, 524287, 2147483647, 2305843009213693951]` by `2^21` (probably via bit-shift) so that when we take their product, we've included an overall factor of `(2^21)^6=2^126`.

Comment: Ah, clever. That saves a byte on the Jelly answer (not on Vyxal because `126` could be compressed). Thanks!

Comment: [-1 byte for Vyxal](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCu+G6hnHhuZjKgcK74oKGz4RFOuKAuSrOoCIsIiIsIiJd).

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCuzvin5FMwrvHkEU64oC5Ks6gIiwiIiwiIl0=) by factorizing `3772545` for `3, 5, 7, 19, 31, 61`

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`,  <sup><s>40</s></sup>  38 bytes

```factor
4 2 [ "=">array n^v ] bi@ v- Π .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQWFSUWFmskJ1alJeao5CbWJKhV5qXmZyfkgrhlKWCVBcrFBSllpRUFhRl5pUoWP83UTBSiFZQYmZlF5a3VbIDG6KQF1emEKuQlOmgUKarcG6Bgt7//wA)

-2 bytes from porting @alephalpha's [PARI/GP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251355/97916).

Note `"="` is a literal string that is equivalent to `{ 3 5 7 19 31 61 }`. You can only see the `=` since the rest are non-printable, but you can see the non-printable characters on TIO. This needs to be converted to an array because `n^v` is buggy otherwise. Still 4 bytes shorter than the sequence literal.

- `4 2 [ ... ] bi@` Apply `[ ... ]` to both 4 and 2.
- `{ 3 5 7 19 31 61 } n^v` Input raised to 3, input raised to 5, etc.
- `v-` Subtract two vectors.
- `Π` Take the product.
- `.` Print the result to stdout.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash, 47 Bytes

```
echo "14448825433*(2^31-1)*(2^61-1)*(2^126)"|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BydDExMTCwsjUxNhYS8MozthQ11ATxDCDMQyNzDSVapKS//8HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 32 bytes

```
8^42##&@@(2^{3,5,7,19,31,61}-1)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yLOxEhZWc3BQcMortpYx1THXMfQUsfYUMfMsFbXUFPtf0BRZl5JdFp0bOx/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 51 bytes

*Thanks JoKing and Steffan for helping me golf some bytes*

```
?-X is(2^61-1)*14448825433*(2^31-1)*2^126,write(X).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/3143QiGzWMMozsxQ11BTy9DExMTCwsjUxNhYCyhoDBY0ijM0MtMpL8osSdWI0NT7/x8A)

My very first Prolog answer :D, probably can be golfed a lot though.

Comment: you can just do `write(X)`.

Comment: also you can change `X is 14448825433*(2^61-1)` to `X is(2^61-1)*14448825433` to save a byte. unfortunately it's the same length to use `format`: `?-format("~d",(2^61-1)*14448825433*(2^31-1)*2^126).`

Comment: @Steffan ah ok didn't know that, will fix

Comment: @Steffan ok that format trick is cool

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <sup><s>21</s> <s>19</s> <s>18</s></sup> 14 bytes

```
3772545YfWtqhp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39jc3MjUxDQyLbykMKPg/38A)

```
3772545YfWtqhp
3772545Yf         # Prime factorize 3772545 (3, 5, 7, 19, 31, 61)
         W        # 2 ** elements
          t       # duplicate list
           q      # decrement elements in copy by 1
            h     # concatenate lists 
             p    # product
```

-2 bytes thanks to @Luis Mendo

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＩΠＥＸ²⁻Ｅ357COm℅ι⁴⁸×ι⊖ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYm7CsMwDAB/xWRSwFmalhY6pmuIh/6AsAUV@BFkJ/l8tekNN9z5D4ovGFWdcG4wYW3gpITNN5hxBVcOErhYM3Pe6j914@0@LamzZpHAGSNw31tzfZx@c6IKbM2LvFCi3Cic/8dTVYc9fgE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
       357COm           Literal string `357COm`
      Ｅ                 Map over characters
              ι         Current character
             ℅          ASCII code
     ⁻                  Vectorised subtract
               ⁴⁸       Literal integer `48`
   Ｘ                    Vectorised exponentiate with base
    ²                   Literal integer `2`
  Ｅ                     Map over powers of `2`
                    ι   Current power of `2`
                   ⊖    Decremented
                 ×      Multiplied by
                  ι     Current power of `2`
 Π                      Take the product
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
357HT╟)]ó_(m*ε*
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/Y1Nwj5NHU@ZqxhzfHa@Rqnduq9f8/AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
3        # Push 3
 5       # Push 5
  7      # Push 7
   H     # Push 19
    T    # Push 31
     ╟   # Push 60
      )  # Increase the 60 by 1
       ] # Wrap the stack into a list: [3,5,7,19,31,61]
ó        # Calculate 2 to the power each of these integers
 _       # Duplicate the list
  (      # Decrease each by 1
   m*    # Multiply the values at the same positions in the lists together
     ε*  # Product: reduce by multiplication
         # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>16 15</s> 12.5 bytes

```
`*.`D62*;^2$-$~ a8532dc3
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWOxK09BJczIy0rOOMVHRV6hQSLUyNjVKSjSHSUFUw1QA)

*-2.5 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen*

Nibbles has no prime-related built-ins, so I had to resort to good old base conversion.

```
`*.`D62*;^2$-$~ a8532dc3
`*                       Product
  .                       for each n in
   `D62                    convert from base 62
                a8532dc3    2824023491
       *                   multiply
         ^2                 2 to the power of
           $                 n
        ;    $              with itself
            - ~              minus 1
```

Comment: [14 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWuxK0FLV1Da31ElzMjOKMVBy0FBItTI2NUpKNIQqg6mDqAQ)

Comment: [12.5 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWOxK09BJczIy0rOOMVHRV6hQSLUyNjVKSjSHSUFUw1QA)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Nice, I didn't notice that the 126 is the sum of the exponents. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
₆¨*≬K₍L∑¨=∆Kc
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigobCqCriiaxL4oKNTOKIkcKoPeKIhktjIiwiIiwiIl0=)

<sup>half-</sup>Legitimate calculation <s>is</s> was shorter than hard coding lol. Given enough time and memory, this would eventually output the right number.

### Explained

```
₆¨*≬K₍L∑¨=∆Kc
₆¨*≬        c   # From all multiples of 64 (which contains the target number), get the first where:
    K₍L∑        #   The list [len(factors), sum(factors)]
        ¨=∆K    #   Is invariant under sum of proper divisors
```

Comment: If the code means "last of the first two integers that are sublime", it isn't correct because there might be an unknown odd sublime number before the 2nd even one.

Comment: @Steffan That was exactly the [initial version of this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/251354/1) and my first comment explains why it doesn't work.

Comment: You could speed things up slightly by replacing `₆` with `₈`, because the target number is a multiple of 256.

Comment: It's no longer shorter than hardcoding it :P

Comment: why does my answer appear higher than yours, lol

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>49 46</s> 45 bytes

Did some google calculation.

```python
print(2**126*14448825433*(2**31-1)*(2**61-1))
```

Comment: There are some more easy golfs, which will lead to basically [xnor's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251352/78410).

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 33 bytes

```
{Jfc~]++==}s1r1f{fcsa%1!j++%1!&&}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/2istuS5WW9vWtrbYsMgwrTotuThR1VAxS1sbSKqp1f7/DwA)

Given infinite time, should find sublime numbers

```
{    # IsPerfect function
 J   # Duplicate
 fc  # Factors
 ~]  # Without self
 ++  # Sum
 ==  # Equals self
}s1  # Store as "1"
r1   # Range 1..inf
f{   # Filter
 fc  # Factors
 sa  # Non-destructive Length
 %1! # IsPerfect
 j++ # Sum of factors
 %1! # IsPerfect
 &&  # And
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁹Æs;ÆdÆṣƑƲ1#
```

A full program that will (eventually!) print the result.

[Don't Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//4oG5w4ZzO8OGZMOG4bmjxpHGsjEj//8)
The `⁹` starts the search at 256, if one replaces it with `1` it'll find `12` - try that **[here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/wcFux9eG2lMNtD3cuPjbx2CZD5f//AQ)**.

---

Faster in 13:

```
“;Y,’Æf2*×’$P
```

Try it [here](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxzrSJ1HDTMPt6UZaR2eDmSpBPz/DwA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 17 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 13.99 bytes

```
3772545AF2@D1-z*P
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYbjc3NjUxNTB3djBxcDHWrtAIg4lBpmDIA)

Port of [Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251370/114446).

```python
3772545AF2@D1-z*P
3772545            # Push 3772545                (there's no integer compression in Thunno)
       AF          # Prime factors of that       ([3, 5, 7, 19, 31, 61])
         2@        # 2 ** each one               ([8, 32, 128, 524288, 2147483648, 2305843009213693952])
           D1-     # Duplicate and subtract one  ([7, 31, 127, 524287, 2147483647, 2305843009213693951])
              z*   # Multiply                    ([56, 992, 16256, 274877382656, 4611686016279904256, 5316911983139663489309385231907684352]) 
                P  # Product of the list         (6086555670238378989670371734243169622657830773351885970528324860512791691264)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>22</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
3772545ǰϼ2⇹^Đ⁻*Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9weXT//zM3NzI1NDXHsM@8MuKHuV7EkOKBuyrOoP//)

```
3772545             push 3, 7, 7, 2, 5, 4, 5
       ǰ            ǰoin elements on stack with no delimiter 
         ϼ          get unique ϼrime factors (casts to integer)
          2⇹^       raise 2 to each power
             Đ⁻     Đuplicate; decrement
               *    element-wise multiplication
                Π   product of list; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 30 bytes

My first Jelly answer! Hope I'll get better in the future.

```
2*’
[3,5,7,19,31,61]ç
¢×/æ«126
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FjdVjbQeNczkijbWMdUx1zG01DE21DEzjD28nOvQosPT9Q8vO7Ta0MhsSXFScjFUy6LoWCgLAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 23 bytes

```
echo*/(,<:)2^q:3772545x
```

Same solution as most answers.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8GCpaUlaboW21OTM_K19DV0bKw0jeIKrYzNzY1MTUwrILJQRTDFAA)

```
echo*/(,<:)2^q:3772545x
               3772545x  NB. extended precision literal
             q:          NB. prime factors
           2^            NB. raise 2 to each factor
      (,<:)              NB. monadic hook 
        <:               NB. decrement
       ,                 NB. concat with hook input
    */                   NB. product reduce
echo                     NB. print
```